# Can I bake a "no bake" cheesecake?

Tags: cheesecake

Random, but I haven't seen this anywhere else.

I realize this can't apply to every "no-bake" cheesecake recipe for good-reason, but I'm wondering if it would be safe to try.

Has anyone ever done it?

Note: This isn't asking for opinion, but rather whether baking a specific "no-bake" cheesecake is plausible to some extent.

I just don't like the mousse consistency in the no-bake recipes.

But, then I got to thinking of how the cheesecakes offered at The Cheesecake Factory all seem to be baked, even the ones that have no-bake versions up on YouTube.

Comment: 1. Why not just use a real cheesecake recipe?
2. Please link to an example recipe so that we can provide you with useful advice.

Comment: I don't think that baking one will remove the mousse consistency you dislike.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be "safe"? Cooking food doesn't make it less safe... you'd just likely waste the ingredients if it didn't work.

Comment: @Catija I assume the OP meant "safe" more figuratively, like "won't just waste my ingredients/time/money", as suggested by "plausible to some extent", not the food safety sense.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I can't say I've browsed through dozens and dozens of no-bake cheesecake recipes but the ones I've looked relied on the ingredients being whipped (usually cream) or gelatin to maintain their shape. Mousse style no-bake cheesecakes use a whipped mixture of gelatin and some milk product that gives the foamy texture.

All no-bake cheesecake recipes (that I've read) require them to be refrigerated before serving. A no-bake cheesecake made with whipped cream, cream cheese, sugar and other ingredients would simply melt into a mess if baked. Ditto for one made with gelatin.

Baked cheesecakes call for eggs and flour to provide structural strength to hold the fats together. I guess if you wanted to add flour and eggs to a no-bake recipe, it might hold some sort of shape. Or not and you get a less spread out mess instead. I really don't think it's at all plausible and I wouldn't want to test it and clean the mess each time.

Comment: Plenty of baked recipes don't include flour (it's in none of the ones I make). I'm fairly certain I've made one with neither flour nor eggs, and if baked very slowly.

Answer (score 3):

I just did and everything’s great!! I used two boxes of jello no bake cheesecake, a quarter of a cup of flour, a teaspoon of vanilla extract, 3 eggs, and about four cups of milk. A single box only calls for a 1 1/2 cups milk, so I doubled for two boxes and added extra to compensate for the flour. I baked for a little over an hour in a preheated 350°F oven. The whole process was winged and just intuitive. I knew I wanted a custard but I was afraid that it wouldn’t  set. After tasting? The consistency is perfect and dense, but if I did this again I would add maybe 1/2 to 3/4 cup of sugar to enhance sweetness. With that said, no one died and the cheesecake browned and set beautifully. I searched the Internet for anyone who may have done this and found nothing. So here it is! It can be done and it can be delicious.

Comment: Congrats! Would you be willing to share a recipe at some point?